# Using imblearn for oversampling multi class data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I want to use **RandomOverSampler** function from **imbalanced-learn** module to perform oversampling the data with more than two classes. The following is my code with 3 classes:

```
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

data = np.random.randn(30,5)
label = np.random.randint(3, size=30)

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=3)
data_res, label_res = ada.fit_sample(data, label)
```

After running, it returns this warning:

> UserWarning: The target type should be binary.   warnings.warn('The
>   target type should be binary.')

But the [documentation](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html#) says:

> Notes
>
> Supports mutli-class resampling.

Am I missing something to use it for multi class case? If this is only for binary class, is there any other library or module which supports multi class oversampling?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation yesterday,
and I used conda to install the library,
I found the file -> base.py
it had something different with the newest version on github.
 

**so I git clone the newest version by github

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn**


and then,
everythings is ok!
u can use multi-class well

Answer (score 0):

You need to update imblearn using :

pip install -U imbalanced-learn

Answer (score 0):

RandomOverSampler() works very well for me on a multi-class problem with 9 labels
I see on your code that you are using ada oversampler instead of ros that you defined.